# Convergence of sequences with sup and inf

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Define a sequence as follows $$b_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n^6} & \text{if n is even} \\ -\frac{1}{n^4} & \text{if n is odd}\end{cases}$$
Let $S = \{b_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. How would you go about proving what the sup, inf, max and min of the set S is? I mean if I write it down the set then its obvious but is there a rigorous way to show this?

Suppose you have to show that $\sup_{m\ \geq 1} \inf_{j \geq m} b_n = \inf_{m \geq 1} \sup_{j \geq m} b_n$. This can help me show that sequence converges to 0. I know from making a picture of the sequence, it converges to 0. But how do I show $\sup_{m\ \geq 1} \inf_{j \geq m} b_n = \inf_{m \geq 1} \sup_{j \geq m} b_n$? In case the notation is confusing, $\sup_{m\ \geq 1} \inf_{j \geq m} b_n$ says that first take the infimum of the sequence given fixed $m$ and then take supremum of those infimum.

P.S. I have just recently started learning sequences so any advanced theory is out of my reach.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have $n\in \mathbb N^*$. Your function is not defined for $n=0$. Then notice that $b_n$ for even $n$ is greater than $0$, and for odd $n$ is less than $0$, so $$b_{2m}>b_{2n+1}, \forall m,n\in\mathbb N^*$$
Then you can deal with two separate sequences, $b_{2n}$ and $b_{2n+1}$. The first one is decreasing, limited above by the first element (maximum=supremum) and below by $0$ (infimum, no minimum). Similarly, the second sequence is limited above by $0$ (supremum, no maximum) and below by the first element (infimum=minimum).

For this problem, using $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit would work easily.

Comment: yeah thats what i was wondering, i have worked with epsilon delta proofs for continuous functions, how would those proofs for sequences look like? Since they arent continuous and we cant be sure if the delta works. Could guide me to a resource that would showcase an epsilon delta proof for sequence?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition is very similar to $\delta-\varepsilon$

Answer (score 0):

Make yourself clear that
$$-\frac1{m^4}\le \inf_{j\ge m}b_j\le -\frac1{(m+1)^4}$$ and in fact one side is an equality, depending on the parity of $m$. Similarly,
$$\frac1{(m+1)^2}\le \sup_{j\ge m}b_j\le \frac1{m^2}.$$